# Will Enabling PDO on Server Impact Existing Production Apps

Tags: php, pdo

I have a server with many PHP/MySQL apps. I am installing an open source system that requires PDO in order to run.

I currently do not have PDO enabled, but can easily do so with the help of my hosting provider.

Will enabling PDO have any impact or bearing on my current running PHP sites and apps?

I see the advantages to having PDO enabled and would plan to take advantage of it going forward. The new OS system is a good nudge to move me in the right direction security-wise. In the meantime, I cannot risk any of my current sites or apps from being effected by turning on PDO -- which will take my HSP about 30-45 minutes to do.

Thanks for the feedback on this step forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other sites/apps do not take advantage of/use PDO (such as in the case of apps that are configurable to use PDO or MySQLi or old mysql_) then no it will have no impact. I'm assuming a majority of your existing apps don't already use PDO or they wouldn't be currently working? PDO doesn't eliminate the old MYSQL_ functions.

Comment: Thanks @hsanders. No, none of my apps use PDO (because it was never enabled) nor did I do any coding to utilize PDO. So it is sounding like I will not have any issues simply by installing PDO on my server. COrect?

Comment: Status Update: enabled PDO last night and it had no effect or impact on any of my existing apps.